# BackgroundService memory leak SqlDependency

Tags: cmd, dependency-injection, sqldependency

this is my service code

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    public bool isRegister { get; set; }
    public bool checkIp { get; set; }
    public long timePass { get; set; }

    public Worker()
    {
    }

    public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (isRegister == false)
                registerSelect();
            if (checkIp == true)
            {
                checkIp = false;
                await SecurityConfig.cacheServices?.BuildServiceProvider()?.GetService<IBlockFirewallIpService>().RegisterInFirewall();
            }
            timePass += 1000;
            if (timePass % 60000 == 0)
                await SecurityConfig.cacheServices?.BuildServiceProvider()?.GetService<IBlockFirewallIpService>().RegisterInFirewall();

            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }

    public void registerSelect()
    {
        isRegister = true;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetDbConnection()))
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlDependency.Start(GetDbConnection());

            string commandText = "SELECT [Ip1],[Ip2] ,[Ip3] ,[Ip4] FROM dbo.BlockFirewallIps where IsRead is null";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn))
            {
                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);

                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    void OnDependencyChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Insert)
            checkIp = true;
        SqlDependency temp = sender as SqlDependency;
        if (temp != null)
            temp.OnChange -= new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);

        registerSelect();
    }

    private string GetDbConnection()
    {
        return GlobalConfig.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
    }
}
```

and this is my IBlockFirewallIpService.RegisterInFirewall() code

```
 public async Task RegisterInFirewall()
    {
        var allBlockIps = await db.BlockFirewallIps.Where(t => t.IsRead == null).ToListAsync();
        foreach (var ip in allBlockIps)
        {
            BanIP("OjeFirTCP" + ip.Ip1 + "_" + ip.Ip2 + "_" + ip.Ip3 + "_" + ip.Ip4, ip.Ip1 + "." + ip.Ip2 + "." + ip.Ip3 + "." + ip.Ip4, "Any", "TCP");
            BanIP("OjeFirUDP" + ip.Ip1 + "_" + ip.Ip2 + "_" + ip.Ip3 + "_" + ip.Ip4, ip.Ip1 + "." + ip.Ip2 + "." + ip.Ip3 + "." + ip.Ip4, "Any", "UDP");
            ip.IsRead = true;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    void BanIP(string RuleName, string IPAddress, string Port, string Protocol)
    {
        if (OperatingSystem.IsWindows())
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(RuleName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(IPAddress) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Port) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Protocol) && new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()).IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator))
            {
                using (Process RunCmd = new Process())
                {
                    RunCmd.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                    RunCmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                    RunCmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=\"" + RuleName + "\" dir=in action=block remoteip=" + IPAddress + " remoteport=" + Port + " protocol=" + Protocol;
                    RunCmd.Start();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this is progeram.cs

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
 .UseWindowsService(options =>
 {
     options.ServiceName = "OjeFirewall";
 })
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
    GlobalConfig.Configuration = hostContext.Configuration;
    services.AddScoped<IHttpContextAccessor, FakeIHttpContextAccessor>();
    SecurityConfig.Config(services);
    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
})
.Build();
```

await host.RunAsync();

this is SecurityConfig.Config codes

```
 services.AddDbContext<SecurityDBContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(GlobalConfig.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"],
                b => b.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SingleQuery))
                , ServiceLifetime.Singleton
        );

        services.AddSingleton<IIpLimitationWhiteListService, IpLimitationWhiteListService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IIpLimitationBlackListService, IpLimitationBlackListService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IFileAccessRoleService, FileAccessRoleService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IRoleService, RoleService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IBlockClientConfigService, BlockClientConfigService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IBlockAutoIpService, BlockAutoIpService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IBlockFirewallIpService, BlockFirewallIpService>();
```

**the problem :**

this code using too much memory after 3 day
starting ram usage is 20mb after first call (OnDependencyChange) it use 47mb
after 3 day it use 178mb

where i am doing wrong ?!

Comment: How did you measure the amount of memory the service is using?

Comment: i am using .netcore 6 and the published code has exe, i just simply execute the exe in cmd and watch it in windows task manager

Comment: the server is limit on hardware, i dont know  what to do i just cant reset server every 3 day there is so many servers. please help me

Comment: The Windows task manager is a very unreliable method of determining the amount of memory the application uses. Instead take a look at the memory use over time using Windows Performance Monitor (perfmon.exe).

Comment: know after almost 4 day my application using 228 mb private and 29mb shareable and 258mb working set and 293mb commit ( i looking in perfmon.exe)

Comment: AFAIKS the code presented doesn't show a clear culprit of a memory leak. If there is a leak, it might be somewhere else. You might be able to do a deep analysis using Visual Studio memory tools or one of the available commercial memory profiling tools.

Comment: i create dump from memory its name is dump_20220305_133448.dmp ( ram usage is 40mb) and i am no longer run application on cmd , move it to windows service . the dmp file is almost 150mb , i will capture another dmp after memory usage reach to 200mb , can you analyse them for me ?

Comment: after 24 hour ram usage is stable (37mb) i am no longer using cmd and its on debug environment

Comment: could  It be because of the console log ?! every 60 second t-sql printed on cmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found problem

```
await SecurityConfig.cacheServices?.BuildServiceProvider()?.GetService<IBlockFirewallIpService>().RegisterInFirewall();
```

this line code was the problem after change it to normal injection ram usage is stable now, but i can not understand whay !?